# Is there a way to add a dependency between parameters for scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to characterize the spreading of carbon isotopes caused by nuclear test in the 70's in an ocean model. 
The atmospheric signal is a strong spike, which will be carried to depth with the ocean currents (deeper currents are much slower).

My goal is to detect the onset of the rise in concentration and the rate of increase at various depth levels.

I assume that the oceanic concentration of carbon isotopes behaves like a piecewise linear function with 3 segments:

1. A constant initial value (`b`) up until time (`t_0`)
2. A linear increase in concentrations from time (`t_0`) to (`t_1`) with the rate `m1`.
3. A linear decrease in concentration after time(`t_1`) with the rate `m2`

I am representing the function using this code in python:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as sio

def piecewise_linear( t, t0, t1, b, m1, m2 ):
    condlist = [ t < t0,
                (t >= t0 ) & ( t < t1 ),
                t >= t1
               ]
    funclist = [lambda t: b,
                lambda t: b + m1 * ( t - t0 ),
                lambda t: b + m1 * ( t - t0 ) + m2 * ( t - t1 )
               ]
    return np.piecewise( t, condlist, funclist )
```

For a given time array `t` I want to be able to fit two 'types' of this function:

1. A full 3-segment line, which is representative of the upper ocean, where the signal propagates fast and the spike is fully captured.
2. A special case, where at the end of the time series the concentration has not peaked (this would represent the signal in the deep ocean, where it takes a long time to propagate the signal)

As example

```
t = np.arange( 0, 15, 0.1 )
y_full = piecewise_linear( t, 5, 10, 2, 2, -4 )
y_cut = piecewise_linear( t, 5, 15, 2, 2, -4 )
plt.plot( t, y_full )
plt.plot( t, y_cut )
plt.legend( [ 'surface', 'deep ocean' ] )
```

[image]

For the first case I am getting good results, when I try to fit the function to the signal after adding some random noise:

```
noise = np.random.normal( 0, 1, len( y_full ) ) * 1
y = y_full
yy = y_full + noise
bounds = ( [ 0, 0, 0, 0, -np.inf ], [ np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, 0 ] )
fit,_ = sio.curve_fit( piecewise_linear, t, yy, bounds=bounds )
print( fit )
y_fit = piecewise_linear( t, *tuple( fit ) )
plt.plot( t, yy, color='0.5' )
plt.plot( t, y_fit, linewidth=3 )
plt.plot( t, y, linestyle='--', linewidth=3 )
```

Which results in

```
>>[  5.00001407  10.01945313   2.13055863   1.95208167  -3.95199719]
```

[image]

However when I try to evaluate the second case (deep ocean), I often get poor results like below:

```
noise = np.random.normal( 0, 1, len(y_full ) ) * 1#
y = y_cut
yy = y_cut+noise
bounds = ( [ 0, 0, 0, 0, -np.inf], [ np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, 0 ] )
fit,_ = sio.curve_fit( piecewise_linear, t, yy, bounds=bounds )
print( fit )
y_fit = piecewise_linear( t, *tuple( fit ) )
plt.plot( t, yy, color='0.5' )
plt.plot( t, y_fit, linewidth=3 )
plt.plot( t, y, linestyle='--', linewidth=3 )
plt.legend( [ 'noisy data', 'fit', 'original' ] )
```

I get

```
>>[ 1.83838997  0.40000014  1.51810839  2.56982348 -1.0622842 ]
```

[image]

The optimization determines that `t_0` is larger than `t_1`, which is nonsensical in this context.

Is there a way to build the condition `t_0 < t_1` into the curve fitting? Or do I have to test, which type of curve is given and then fit to two different functions (a 3-segment or 2-segment piecewise linear function)?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You can quickly test a "brick wall" where if a given condition is found, such as t_0 > t_1, then the fitting function returns a very large value - and therefore a very large error. This method is somewhat crude, but often works as a practical matter and has the great virtue of being easy to code and easy to test.

Comment: ... or, you can change the parameterization so that the constraint is always satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using lmfit (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py) for this. 
Lmfit provides a higher-level interface to curve fitting and makes fitting parameters first class python objects.  Among other things, this easily allows fixing some parameters, and setting bounds on parameters in a more pythonic manner than what `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` uses.  In particular for your question, lmfit parameters also support using mathematical expressions as constraint expressions for all parameters.

To turn your model function `piecewise_linear()` into an Model for curve-fitting with lmfit you would do something like

```
from lmfit import Model

# make a model
mymodel = Model(piecewise_linear)

# create parameters and set initial values
# note that parameters are *named* from the 
# names of arguments of your model function
params = mymodel.make_params(t0=0, t1=1, b=3, m1=2, m2=2)

# now, you can place bounds on parameters, maybe like
params['b'].min = 0
params['m1'].min = 0

# but what you want is an inequality constraint, so
#   1. add a new parameter 'tdiff'
#   2. constrain t1 = t0 + tdiff
#   3. set a minimum value of 0 for tdiff
params.add('tdiff', value=1, min=0)
params['t1'].expr = 't0 + tdiff'

# now perform the fit
result = mymodel.fit(yy, params, t=t)

# print out results
print(result.fit_report())
```

You can read in the lmfit docs or on other SO questions how to extract other information from the fit result.

Comment: Can anyone comment on why this was downvoted?  I thought it did address the question, and would like to understand why someone thought otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `curve_fit` has several disadvantages such that the solution of MNewille is something to think about. Moreover, `curve_fit` has no parameter `args` (in contrast to, e.g., `leastsq`), which might allow to switch off the second slope. A second fit function without `m2` might be a solution, here. If, however, `curve_fit` is a must, and a generic fit function working in both cases is required, a solution might look like (note the starting parameters extracted from the data):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as sio

"""
 we know t0 > 0, t1 > t0, b>0, m1 > 0, m2 < 0
"""
def piecewise_linear( t, t0, a , b, m1, m2 ):
    t0 = abs( t0 )
    t1 = abs( a ) * t0
    b = abs( b )
    m1 = abs( m1 )
    m2 = - abs( m2 )
    condlist = [ t < t0,
                 ( t >= t0 ) & ( t < t1 ),
                 t >= t1
               ]
    funclist = [ lambda t: b,
                 lambda t: b + m1 * ( t - t0 ),
                 lambda t: b + m1 * ( t - t0 ) + m2 * ( t - t1 )
               ]
    return np.piecewise( t, condlist, funclist )

t = np.arange( 0, 15, 0.1 )
y_full = piecewise_linear( t, 5, 2, 2, 2, -4 )
y_cut = piecewise_linear( t, 5, 3, 2, 2, -4 )

####################

#~ plt.plot( t, y_full )
#~ plt.plot( t, y_cut )
#~ plt.legend( [ 'surface', 'deep ocean'] )

####################

#~ noise = np.random.normal( 0, 1, len( y_full ) ) * 1
#~ y = y_full
#~ yy = y_full + noise

#~ bounds = ( [ 0, 0, 0, 0, -np.inf ], [ np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, 0 ] )
#~ fit,_ = sio.curve_fit( piecewise_linear, t, yy, bounds=bounds )
#~ print( fit )
#~ y_fit = piecewise_linear( t, *tuple( fit ) )
#~ plt.plot( t, yy, color='0.5' )
#~ plt.plot( t, y_fit, linewidth=3 )
#~ plt.plot( t, y, linestyle='--', linewidth=3 )

####################

noise = np.random.normal( 0, 1, len( y_full ) ) * 1
y = y_cut
yy = y_cut + noise
tPos = np.argmax( yy )
t1Start = t[ tPos ]
t0Start = t[ tPos // 2 ]
bStart = yy[ 0 ]
aStart = 2
m1Start = ( yy[ tPos ] - yy[ tPos // 2 ] ) / ( t1Start - t0Start )

p0 = [ t0Start, aStart, bStart, m1Start, 0 ])
fit,_ = sio.curve_fit( piecewise_linear, t, yy, p0=p0 )
print( fit )
y_fit = piecewise_linear( t, *tuple( fit ) )

plt.plot( t, yy, color='0.5' )
plt.plot( t, y_fit, linewidth=3 )
plt.plot( t, y, linestyle='--', linewidth=3 )
plt.legend( [ 'noisy data', 'fit', 'original' ] )
plt.show()
```

It works on the test data. One  has to keep in mind that the returned fit parameters might be negative. As the function takes the modulus, this needs to be done on the returned parameters as well. Also note that `t1` is not fitted directly any more, but as a multiple of `t0`. Errors, hence, need to be propagated accordingly. The new structure does not require `bounds`.

Also note, the choice of starting parameters `p0` should  work for case 1, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Extracting the starting points from the data was a great addition.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't known what exactly is the regression algorithm used in Python, I cannot really answer to your question. Probably the algorithm is an iterative process as usual.

As additional information, I would show a very simple method which can give an approximate answer without iterative process nor initial guess. The theory based on the fitting of an integral equation can be found in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales and some examples of the use in case of piecewise function are shown in : https://fr.scribd.com/document/380941024/Regression-par-morceaux-Piecewise-Regression-pdf

In the case of a piecewise function made of three linear segments, the method of calculus is given page 30 of the second above paper. It is very easy to write a code in any computer language. I suppose that it is possible with Python too.

From the data obtained by scanning the original graph :

[image]

The method of regression with integral equation leads to the next result :

[image]

The fitted equation is :
[image]

H is the Heaviside function.

The values of the parameters a1, a2, p1, q1, p2, q2, p3, q3 are given on the above figure.

One can see that the first segment is not exactly horizontal as expected. But the slope is very small : 0.166

It is possible to specify a slope=0 (that is p1=0) thanks to a slight change in the second part of the algorithm. The modified algorithm is shown below :

[image]

Now, the result is :

[image]